# Create file in SharePoint Online without using SharePoint Client Model in C#

Tags: development, sharepoint-online, file

In C#, I want to create a file in my SharePoint Online site **without** using SharePoint client object model.

I am trying to use SharePoint REST APIs and List methods.

I don't want to use `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` as the use of this DLL requires installation of `SharePoint Client Components` on the client server.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code in Javascript:

```
executor.executeAsync({
  url: "<app web url>/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web
    /getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/Shared Documents/filename.docx')
    /savebinarystream
    ?@target='<host web url>'",
  method: "POST",
  body: "This is the new content.",
  success: successHandler,
  error: errorHandler
});
```

It creates a file from the file system to your sharepoint online site. Kindly validate if this is the needed answer.

You can refer to this link for more informations : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_FileSaveBinaryStream

Comment: Thank you. But, I am writing C# (plugin) code and not a JavaScript code.

Comment: You can try this [link](http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.com/2014_07_01_archive.html), there's an exemple of how to call REST service from C#. Can you give it a try ?